# Get the substring from a filename and compare to Hour (HH) of current date/timestamp using Shell Script

Tags: shell, date

Say I have a filename `ABC.20131212.XX.xml` where `XX` is HH (hour). I need to get the value of `XX` and compare it to the current hour of the system time. If it's equal, then, i'll rename that file. So if it's 12pm (12:00), I should get the file with `ABC.20131212.12.xml` and rename it. How can I achieve the comparison in shell script?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add the sample code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get started in pure bash without starting external commands:

```
a=ABC.20131212.XX.xml
# Strip off .xml
b=${a%.xml}
# Extract last 2 characters
xx=${b: -2}
```

and the hour can be got with

```
time=`date +'%H'`
```

Comparison and rename can be done like this

```
if [[ $time -eq $xx ]]
then
   mv something somewhere
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using Bash built-in regex matching:

```
file=foobar.11.xml
if [[ $file =~ .*([0-9][0-9])\.xml ]]; then
    if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" -eq $(date "+%I") ]]; then
        # $file has current hour in its name
    fi
fi
```

Use the `+%H` option with `date` for comparing to a 24-hour time system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Script you can use(Change path accordingly):
`

## !/bin/bash

Path=/Your/Path/Here/*

for l in $Path

do

a=$l

b=${a%.xml}

xx=${b: -2}

time=`date +"%I"`

if [[ $time -eq $xx ]]

then

```
mv $l /New/file/name/path/newfile.txt
```

fi

done

exit 0`